# IS TABLE OF and AS TABLE OF when creating PL/SQL nested table collection types

Tags: oop, plsql, types, syntax, nested-table

I am curious about syntax usage with PL/SQL collection type creations. What is the difference between `is table of` and `as table of` when creating a PL/SQL nested table collection type, if any? I've seen only `is table of` in the Oracle help documentation but code I've come across uses both `is table of` and `as table of` when creating the collection type. I tried both and both statements appear to execute at the same speed and hold data as intended.

For example, for object type

```
create or replace type new_emp_ot is object
(
    ssn number(9),
    lname varchar2(200),
    fname varchar2(200)
);
```

is there any discernible difference between how Oracle processes

```
create or replace type new_emp_nt as table of new_emp_ot;
```

and

```
create or replace type new_emp_nt is table of new_emp_ot;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IS` and `AS` are [interchangeable in the CREATE TYPE syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034__I2064507), there is no difference in this case.

Although the syntax diagram is incorrect... it makes it look like IS/AS are optional, but you can't actually omit them.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think to check there. Also good catch with the syntax diagram.

Comment: I'm so used to Oracle's inflexible syntax that I had to ask and now I'm surprised to learn there are interchangeable keywords in a `create type` statement!